# Is it correct to say we have five sense organs?

Tags: grammatical-number, countable-nouns

There is a difference in type of something and actual number of that thing as per my understanding. 
Saying, we have five senses or five kinds of sense organs is okay, but when I say we have five sense organs, that seems incorrect. Eyes should be counted twice.

Consider the following examples.

> We have five sense organs

from [link](https://byjus.com/biology/sense-organs/).

From yet another [link](https://www.organsofthebody.com/), we get the following sentence.

> Names of 78 Organs of The Body

They have counted the organs which come in pairs like eyes, kidneys, etc. only once.
Again if they were to say we have 78 *kinds* of organs, that would have made sense.

I believe there is something quite wrong in my usage of English language as there are so many examples which go against my line of thought.
English is not my primary language so there is a high chance of that happening.
I would however like to learn and understand where I went wrong, and would like to know which grammar topic should I refresh to understand this better.

Comment: There are also two ears and two nostrils. Plus, how would you count *skin* which is a mass noun and has no number? Unless you are being incredibly literal (and I don't know how you would deal with skin if you were), it's understood idiomatically that the answer is 5, and not (theoretically) 8+.

Comment: Will it be okay to conclude that statements like "There are 78 organs" implicitly mean that they are referring to kind/types of organs, and not the actual count?

Comment: Normally, I would assume that to be the case. But also note the actual definition of [*organ*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/organ) (emphasis mine): "bodily parts performing a function or **cooperating in** an activity." It seems that even literally, there's a distinction made between bodily *parts* (two eyes) and a functional "organ" (the eyes). The first sense of the word also suggests this, where an organ is a "structure."

Comment: There is a distinction in counting between ‘type’ and ‘token’.  If you ask “how many nuts are there in the world?”, you might be asking about either the types of nut (walnut, peanut etc..) or about the number of actual nuts (the tokens, including all types.  This is a fact of usage we accept and live with (by using strategies to avoid ambiguity). Similarly, the use of ‘organ’ is a biologically vague and potentially (to the literal minded) misleading idiom.  For day to day purposes, we know there are five distinguishing types of sensation (give or take the sixth!), and call them organs.

Comment: @Tuffy That's exactly my point. The ambiguity regarding "There are (say) 5 nuts in the world" can be resolved in one of the 2 ways. One is that we accept that there is a hidden mention of kind/type. Other is we change the statement itself to say the "There are x nuts in the world" where x is the actual number.

Comment: @SahilSingh I would love it as much as you if everyone paid attention all the time to completely precise unambiguous expression.  But the world of human language is not like that.  I have checked Five other European languages, all of which use the equivalent expression.  So, as far as I can tell, do Chinese, Gujarati and Arabic.  Probably, if you asked, most of us would say they are the eyes, ears, nose (or nostrils), mouth (or tongue) and hands (or perhaps fingers).   You will find it in toddler’ picture books.  It won’t do for medical students, but day to day it’s how people speak.

Comment: I am not sure how English plays into any of this. I have the exact same number of eyes in every language. More to the point, why do you want to use "sense organs" at all. People just don't count sense organs, they count senses. And again, that is not something specific to English.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I see the phrase "sense organs" being used a lot of times. The link given above is one example.